# Error running a query in MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

[image]

```
select 
    tblproduct.itemname As Item_Name, 
    ((sum(tblpurchase.[case]) * tblproduct.pc)-
    ((sum(tblsale.[case]) * tblproduct.pc)+(sum(tblsale.nos)))) 
As Remaining_Stock
From 
    (tblproduct 
left Join 
    tblpurchase on tblproduct.itemname=tblpurchase.itemname) 
left join 
    tblsale on tblproduct.itemname = tblsale.itemname 
where 
    tblproduct.itemname='Combo Soap' 
group by 
    tblproduct.itemname
```

Error is shown in the screenshot. I am unable to run this query. Please help me to find solution how to solve and run this query! Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with VB.NET. Please don't add tags that are irrelevant to the actual problem. The fact that your app is written in VBN doesn't make any difference if the issue is in the SQL, which would be the same an application written in any language.

Comment: When you use aggregate functions and a `GROUP BY` clause, EVERY column must appear in one or the other. You are not aggregating `tblproduct.pc` or grouping it, so that's invalid SQL. I think that it should be enough to group by that column, but I haven't tested so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: so, sir how to aggregating tblproduct.pc or grouping it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
select 
    tblproduct.itemname As Item_Name, 
    sum(tblpurchase.[case] * tblproduct.pc) -
    sum(tblsale.[case] * tblproduct.pc) +
    sum(tblsale.nos) As Remaining_Stock
from

<snip>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nothing change same error

Comment: Try again. It runs nicely, though the result is different.

Comment: sir, you are right, but result is double example : **_(5 x 4)- ((3 x 4) + 3)=5_** but above reply code result is double like **10**

Comment: OK, but can't help as the sample data doesn't match your example calculations. But, now when the query runs, adjust your formula/expressions to deliver the required result.

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to all of you who helped me move forward, so I could solve this query.

```sql
SELECT tblproduct.itemname,
       ( 
        Sum(tblpurchase_grouped.total_case) * Sum(tblproduct.pc) + 
        Sum(tblpurchase_grouped.total_nos)
       ) - 
       ( 
        Sum(tblsale_grouped.total_case) * Sum(tblproduct.pc) +
        Sum(tblsale_grouped.total_nos)
       ) AS Total
FROM (tblproduct
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT itemname,
          SUM(nos) AS total_nos,
          SUM([case]) AS total_case
   FROM tblsale
   GROUP BY itemname
) AS tblsale_grouped
  ON tblproduct.itemname = tblsale_grouped.itemname)
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT itemname,
          SUM(nos) AS total_nos,
          SUM([case]) AS total_case
   FROM tblpurchase
   GROUP BY itemname
) AS tblpurchase_grouped 
   ON tblproduct.itemname = tblpurchase_grouped.itemname
WHERE tblproduct.itemname='Maza'
GROUP BY tblproduct.itemnam
```